# JavaFX Deployment with external JDBC Jar File

Tags: jdbc, deployment, ant, classpath, javafx-8

**Let me start off by saying that when compiling the code base everything works fine and I can connect to the SQL Server Express 2012 database.** The problem:

I have is that when I create a windows executable file and eventhough the Sqljdbc41.jar is included in the distribution i.e. is located in the following folder `"myProject\app\lib\sqljdbc41.jar"`

my application cannot seem to find this jar file to make a connection. I get the following exception thrown:

Note: this exception does not appear when compiling my code base in Netbeans it only appears when my application is installed on a development machine to test after installation.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver 
 found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=NORTHWND;
```

I'm using Netbeans 8.0.1 with the following settings:

Under Tools --> Option I have this listed under the Java Ant tab:

```
C:\Users\Zermatt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myProject\src\myProject\Microsoft\sqljdbc41.jar
```

Under the Project tab in **`Netbeans for myProject`** I have:

Under the Libraries Folder

```
 --> sqljdbc41.jar which is pointing to src/myProject/Microsoft/sqljdbc41.jar under Project Properties --> Library --> Compile tab
```

Under the Services tab I even have made the following:

Under the Databases tree

```
 --> Drivers --> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 registered connection to verify connection in my project.
```

So what am I missing or not doing correctly? I'm wondering can I, or do I need to somehow explicitly mention a classpath in the ANT script? This is the first time I have used ANT so it's still a learning curve for me!

Below is the ANT script I am using in my build.xml file:

```
<fx:deploy width="${javafx.run.width}" height="${javafx.run.height}"

          nativeBundles="EXE"

          outdir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" outfile="${application.title}">

    <fx:application name="${application.title}"

                    version="1.0.0"

                    mainClass="${javafx.main.class}"

                    preloaderClass="firstPreloader.FirstPreloader"/>

    <fx:permissions elevated="true"/>

    <fx:preferences shortcut="true" menu="true" install="true"/>

    <fx:resources>

        <fx:fileset id="preloader-files" requiredFor="preloader" dir="${basedir}/dist/lib" includes="FirstPreloader.jar"/>

        <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>

        <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="lib/*.jar"/>

        <fx:fileset os="windows" type="license" includes="license.rtf" dir="${basedir}/src/myProject/package" />

        <fx:fileset os="windows" type="data" includes="config.properties" dir="${basedir}" />

        <fx:fileset dir="build" type="native" os="windows" arch="x64" includes="native-libs-win-x86_64.jar"/>

    </fx:resources>

    <fx:info title="${application.title}"

             vendor="${application.vendor}">

        <fx:icon href="./package/windows/myProject.ico"/>

        <fx:splash href="./package/windows/myProject_Splash.png"/>

    </fx:info>

</fx:deploy>
```

I'll admit that I am grasping at straws now, I'm still having no success and I have even done the following:

In the manifest file I have:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: C:\Users\Zermatt\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myProject\src\myProject\Microsoft\sqljdbc41.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build

Sandwiched between the target tag and (fx deploy) tag I have finally worked out how to use the (fx jar) tag:

```
<fx:jar destfile="${basedir}/${dist.dir}/myProject.jar">
    <fx:application name="myProject Application" mainClass="myProject.myProject"/>
        <fx:resources>
            <fx:fileset dir="${basedir}/${dist.dir}" includes="lib/*.jar"/>
        </fx:resources>
        <fx:fileset dir="build/classes"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${basedir}sqljdbc41.jar"/>
        </manifest>
</fx:jar>
```

But I'm still getting the same exception as before! So how do I do this? Help please!

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Netbeans or project structure. You need to add sql jar file to classpath before launching the main class.

This link may help you: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html